# I cant use background-color inside <footer>

Tags: css, footer, background-color

Somehow, I can't bring the footer to show with the desired color I wish. Could someone help me?

My whole css:

```
        body{
            width:900px;
            margin: 10px auto;
            border-top  : 1px solid black;
            border-left  : 1px solid black;
            border-right  : 1px solid black;
            position:relative;
            min-height:550px;
            background-color:#B8BBBD;

        }
        header {
            height:150px;
            background:red;
            position:relative;
        }
        header div.nadpis {
            color:maroon;
            font-size:48px;
            position:absolute;
            left:50px;
            top:50px;
        }
        nav {
            min-height:20px;
            background: rgb(30,87,153); /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(41,137,216,1)), color-stop(99%,rgba(32,124,202,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 99%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 99%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#207cca',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        }
        nav ul {
            display:block;
            margin:0;
            padding:10px;

        }
        nav ul li {
            display:inline-block;
            padding:1px 10px;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
        }
        nav ul li:last-child{

            border-right: none;
        }
        nav a{
            color:white;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        nav a:hover{
            text-decoration:underline;
            color: rgb(255,0,0);
        }
        main{
            float:left;
            min-width:690px;
            background-color: #fff;
            min-height:300px;
            padding: 5px 5px;

        }
        aside{
            float:right;
            width:200px;
            min-height:310px;
            background:orange;
        }
        }

        footer{
            min-height: 100px;
            background-color: #fff;
            clear:both;
            position: relative;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra closing curly brace after aside.

Comment: oh yes that would do it

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a problem related to your posted css. The `background-color` property works the same on `<footer></footer>` tags as it does for any other html element.

Here is proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/oqr84wsd/1/

What you need to do is verify that your css is not being overwritten by another css file which is being called later in your CSS declarations, or by a user agent sheet style. One way to do this would be to right click the footer and select "inspect element". If the CSS you have written is being overwritten by another style, your code will have a line through it in the CSS window of your inspector.

The only other possibility I can think of is if you were having a z-index issue with an overlapping `<div>`

Comment: thanks alot for answer. Seems like my problem was way more easier to handle then i thought at first. Still i appreciate your help.